# How do i transfer a REST-client to the Android platform

Tags: java, xml, rest

I am using a REST service on in an ordinary java project and it works as it should. What I want to do now is use the same service on an Android app (and get the same result ofc).

```
response = mWebResource.path("/test").accept("application/xml").get(ClientResponse.class);
status = response.getStatus();
if (status == 200 ) {
    TestBean jbl = response.getEntity(TestBean.class);
    System.out.println(jbl);
}
```

On the server side it looks something like this:

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;

@GET
@Path("/test")
@Produces("application/xml")
public TestBean getGetTest(@Context HttpHeaders headers) {
    try {
        TestBean bean = new TestBean();
        return bean;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return new TestBean();
}
```

The result here is the TestBean class instance when I use it in an ordinary java application. How do I get the TestBean into Android? I only succeed in getting an XML stream. My android test code so far looks like this. The key here seems to be that the `response.getEntity` call can't take a class argument.

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
BasicHttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
BasicScheme basicAuth = new BasicScheme();
HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost("192.168.100.114", 80, "http");
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://192.168.100.114/RestWeb/test");
HttpResponse response = client.execute(targetHost, httpget);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
Object content = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
System.out.println(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Android apps run on Java. So in theory you should be able to use the code as it is in an Android app and not have to make many changes. Android does require that all network/internet work be done in a separate thread though. Android apps are also compiled differently from regular Java programs. So you will have to load your code into Eclipse with the Android plugin and build/compile as an Android project. You should be able to accomplish this without having to change your code too much. If your having an issue with a portion of the code try looking at the LogCat for the stack trace. That will give you a head start as to where the problem is at

Comment: I tried that. One of my problems was that jaxb could not translate to dalvik-vm, it did not say why though